# Check if element is child of another in Dart

Tags: onclick, dart, parent-child, dart-html, dart2js

I need to check if a clicked element is child of another, using jQuery I would do: `$(event.target).parents('#foo').length === 1` but with dart I have no clue.

```
void main(){
   (querySelector('body') as BodyElement).onClick.listen(onGlobalClick);
}

onGlobalClick(Event event){
 Element element = event.target;
 //Check if `element` is child of an element with an id of 'foo'
}
```

Comment: Do you want if it is a direct child or a descendant?

Comment: descendant. My aim to create a popover that will disappear when clicked outside of it.

Comment: Ok, then contains is the way to go.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
element.contains(event.target)
```

should return whether `event.target` is a descendant of `element`